# How to derive an question related to connectedness and compactness in topology

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

I am trying assignment questions based on topology and I was unable to think about this particular problem.

For a subset A of the topological space X, let $A'$  denote the union of the set A and all those connected components of X \ A which are relatively compact in X ( i.e. closure is compact) . Then for every subset A of X prove that $A'$ = $ A''$ .

Attempt: $A'$ is subset of $ A''$ is clear by definition.

> But can anyone please tell how can I derive the opposite inclusion.

Comment: What is $A''$? Closure of a set $A$(say) is denoted by $\overline{A}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$To show that $A''\subseteq A'$, we need to show that $X\setminus A'$ has no relatively compact connected components, so let $C$ be a connected component of $X\setminus A'$. Clearly $C\subseteq X\setminus A$, so there is a connected component $D$ of $X\setminus A$ such that $C\subseteq D$. If $\cl D$ were compact, we’d have $C\subseteq D\subseteq A'$, which is impossible, so $\cl D$ is not compact. But this means that $D\cap A'=\varnothing$, since the connected components of $X\setminus A$ are pairwise disjoint, so $C=D$, $\cl C=\cl D$ is not compact, and $C$ is not relatively compact.

Comment: could you please explain how you have concluded that $C$=$D$?

Comment: @NoBinash: $D$ is a connected component of $X\setminus A$, and $D\cap A'=\varnothing$, so $D$ is a connected component of $X\setminus A'$. $C$ is also a connected component of $X\setminus A'$, and $C\subseteq D$, so they must be the same connected component of $X\setminus A'$: $C=D$.